# How to fix "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one" in purrr

Tags: r, purrr, glm, broom

I'm bootstrapping well known `mtcars` dataset and applying logistic regression using `glm` and `purrr::map`. Howevever I'm getting

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

error

I've already tried to apply `glm` to a single bootstrapped data and it works fine, but when I apply `map` function it fails

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)
library(broom)

sample10 <- 
    bootstraps(mtcars, times=10) %>%  
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(data_sample=list(analysis(splits))) %>%
    select(id, data_sample)

sample10

Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   id          data_sample        
   <chr>       <list>             
 1 Bootstrap01 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 2 Bootstrap02 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 3 Bootstrap03 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 4 Bootstrap04 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 5 Bootstrap05 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 6 Bootstrap06 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 7 Bootstrap07 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 8 Bootstrap08 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
 9 Bootstrap09 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
10 Bootstrap10 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
```

when I try to fit a model for each bootstrap dataframe :

```r
sample10 %>% 
    mutate(model_fit = map(data_sample, 
                           ~ glm(formula= vs ~ wt + disp,                    
                                 data=., 
                                 family=binomial)))

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

However when I try to fit a glm to single Bootstrap data frame it is all good

```r
glm(formula= vs ~ wt + disp, data=sample10$data_sample[[1]], family=binomial)


Call:  glm(formula = vs ~ wt + disp, family = binomial, data = sample10$data_sample[[1]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         disp  
    5.54313     -1.19918     -0.01472  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  29 Residual
Null Deviance:      41.18 
Residual Deviance: 16.97    AIC: 22.97
```

The error message is not helpful, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I feel like it's something with `purrr::map` function but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `map` should work `map(sample10$data_sample, ~ glm(vs ~ wt + disp, data = .x, family = binomial))`  In the above, you are trying to create the model output without wrapping in a list

Answer (score 1):

The issue I think is that the tibble is still grouped by row.  If you add `ungroup()` as the last step of your chain then the code will work.

```
sample10 <- bootstraps(mtcars, times=10) %>%  
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(data_sample=(list(analysis(splits)))) %>%
  select(id, data_sample) %>%
  ungroup()

sample10 %>% 
  mutate(model_fit = map(data_sample, 
                         ~ glm(formula= vs ~ wt + disp,                    
                               data=., 
                               family=binomial)))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id          data_sample            model_fit
   <chr>       <list>                 <list>   
 1 Bootstrap01 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 2 Bootstrap02 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 3 Bootstrap03 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 4 Bootstrap04 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 5 Bootstrap05 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 6 Bootstrap06 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 7 Bootstrap07 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 8 Bootstrap08 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
 9 Bootstrap09 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
10 Bootstrap10 <data.frame [32 x 11]> <S3: glm>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! :) Thanks a lot @H 1. I'm wondering though how did you notice I needed to add `as_tibble()` there. Is it because data is grouped (`Groups: <by row>`) if i do not add `as_tibble()`? 

Instead of running with `as_tibble()` I added `ungroup()` and it did indeed worked successfully too.

Comment: @MehmetÖnerYalçın - glad to hear it helped.  There wasn't anything obviously wrong with the code so I suspected the issue was being caused by `rowwise()`.  I agree that `ungroup()` is more appropriate than `as_tibble()` even if the result is the same - have updated the post.